# HTML 5 DOM Storage in IE6/7

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, storage

Anyone knows a better way to storage data in IE6/7 using HTML DOM Storage? I found the [ExDomStorage](http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/ExDOMStorage)
But it limits data to 64Kb.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the userData behavior at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It doesn't provide as much flexibility as the DOM storage mechanism defined by the HTML 5 specification, but should be sufficient for most operations.

As a caveat, for security reasons, I don't recommend making use of this on anything beyond intranet sites or applications.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Refer [MooTools](http://mootools.net/blog/2008/01/22/whats-new-in-12-element-storage/)